# How to disable smart microphone swapping

Tags: bluetooth, microphone

Every time I start Nvidia GeForce now it triggers something in macOS to "intelligently" switch the microphone from my MacBook to [B&W Px7 S2](https://www.bowerswilkins.com/en-us/product/headphones/px7-s2) headphones.

I almost never use my microphone and the quality of the headphones drops significantly because it switches from noise canceling to ambient.

Is there some way to tell macOS to never switch the microphone for me?

Comment: Can you switch it back in System Preferences > Sound > Input? Is there an Nvidia app that allows you to set those preferences? Also you may want to ask this question on the Nvidia Mac forums as they may have more expertise...

Comment: Yes I can switch it back afterwards. In the Nvidia app there doesn't appear to be an option. I think it's something that macOS does intelligently. I will also ask on the Nvidia forums if there's correlation with this.